# in this c program on shell why the segmentation fault error

Tags: c, pointers

why there is **segmentation-fault error** in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[]="cs311cs312cs313";

    printf("%s %s %s %s",
           *word,
           *(word+2),
           *(word+4),
           *(word+8));

    return 0;
}
```

Is this error is due to compiler or there is some syntax error in my code ?

Comment: Remove the `*` from each of those expressions. `printf` with `%s` wants the *pointer* to the string. You're passing the character at each of those locations (the `*` gives you  the element, in this case a `char`, that symbol points to). In other words: `printf("%s %s %s %s", word, word+2, word+4, word+8);`

Comment: thank you so much now there is no  segmentation-fault

Comment: Do you understand now why what you had was incorrect?

Comment: yes i am thinking on it ! trying to get it

Comment: `word` represents the *address* of your string. `*word` is what that address points to. The value returned by `*word` is the character `'c'` which is not a valid address, so you get a segmentation fault. Similarly for `*(word+2)`, etc. `word+2` is the *address* of your string starting at the first `'3'`. But `*(word+2)` returns the actual character, `'3'`, which, again, is not a valid address. The format `%s` in `printf` wants the *address* of a string.

Comment: got it completely ,thank you so much .

Comment: @lurker That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @CoolGuy tried then then got down-voted with no explanation.

Comment: @lurker That doesn't mean that you have to delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers usually give warnings in such situations, for example:

> warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]

`*(word+2)` and others are *pointer dereferencing*, operation gets the actual value the pointer points to. This will give you chars `'c'`, `'3'` and so.

Because `printf` has variable argument count - arguments after the format string will be put on stack raw, loosing types

`%s` makes `printf` take a few bytes from stack and expect it to be a pointer to the string.
Try `printf("Char: %p, str:%p", 'c', "c");` to see what the passed address looks like.

Addresses like `0x63` in the very beginning of memory are valid, but your program is forbidden from accessing these, because the segment is not assigned to it, so you get the `segmentation-fault`/`access violation`

So to fix the error - remove the unwanted dereferencing (the `*`s)